# typeerror argument 'image' must be iplimage

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I am new at opencv. While compiling python code, I am getting the following error.

```
TypeError: argument 'image' must be iplimage
```

Please explain what `iplimage` is and why I am getting this.

Here is my code:

```
import cv
capture=cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
image=cv.QueryFrame(capture)
writer=cv.CreateVideoWriter("output.avi", 0, 15,(800,600) , 1)
count=0
cv.NamedWindow('Image_Window')
while count<250:
    image=cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.WriteFrame(writer, image)
    cv.ShowImage('Image_Window',image)
    cv.WaitKey(2)
    count+=1
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should read the opencv docs. There you will find what an `IplImage` is.

Comment: If you are new to OpenCV then you should not learn legacy interface. There is a new python interface in `cv2` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

IplImage is the basic image class in OpenCV. `cv.QueryFrame` should return an IplImage. But it seems, it doesn't in your case.

You should try to check against `NULL`. `QueryFrame` returns `NULL` instead of an image in case of an error.

Also, check out [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482761/typeerror-argument-image-must-be-iplimage/12486296#12486296) question. You might find your answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing a valid codec to the video writer.  I tried your code and got an error, and then I changed the codec being used and it worked.

You should change this line:

```
writer=cv.CreateVideoWriter("output.avi", 0, 15,(800,600) , 1)
```

to this:

```
writer=cv.CreateVideoWriter("output.avi", cv.CV_FOURCC('i','Y', 'U', 'V'), 15,(800,600) , 1)
```

However [Andrey Kamaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724461/andrey-kamaev) is correct in saying that you should rather not be using the `cv` interface, the newer `cv2` interface is both easier and more reliable.  [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290023/opencv-2-4-in-python-video-processing/12333066#12333066) I covered how to write image frames to a file using the `cv2` interface.

If the above mentioned codec does not work for you, I am afraid you might be in for some trouble.  You may refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136989/creating-avi-files-in-opencv/1137034#1137034) to learn more about finding a valid codec.